# post data to server on android

Tags: android, json, post

I'm trying to post data to a server using cakephp api. Using postman my api works fine but on Android I got some problem. I'm using asynctask for that but I think I may have a problem with the json to post.
I got an error message telling me that

```
 org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

this my code ,could you please tell me what's wrong with it ?

```
public class AsycTaskManager {

    public static class AddApplication extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        String result ;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String addFlightPlanUrl = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8765/car/addapplication";
            String token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjIsImV4cCI6MTUwMTczOTkyNH0.5dwPuoScLdI3ivkuJ6afpmST6D5MwuoAcOzQ0EGBLAY";

            String postData ;
            URL object = null;
            try {
                object = new URL(addFlightPlanUrl);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) object.openConnection();
                con.setDoOutput(true);
                con.setDoInput(true);
                con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", token);
                con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

                con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                JSONObject cred = new JSONObject();

                cred.accumulate("code", "2");
                cred.accumulate("name", "2");


                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
                wr.write(cred.toString());
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                int HttpResult = con.getResponseCode();
                if (HttpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    br.close();
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(sb.toString());

                    result = jObj.toString();

                    if (result != null) {
                        return result;
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println(con.getResponseMessage());
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Log.e("result","null "+result);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

After debugging it appears that I may have problems with cakephp . i got this error message:

```
Deprecated: Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknownon line 0
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in Unknown on line 0
Warning (512): Unable to emit headers. Headers sent in file= line=0 [CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 48]
```

But I don't know why it works with postman and it's not working with android !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the `<br` message of the exception I think that your server is expecting some header or something similar that Postman is sending and you don't, then the server is answering an error page (that's why you get the HTML 
 tag.
You can add Facebook's [Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) tool to compare the raw request you're sending against Postman's one.

**But** even if you solve that, I recommend you to stop using both the `AsyncTask` and the `HttpURLConnection`. There're a lot of tools that can make your life too much easier. I think your best choice if [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Hope it helps, regards!

**EDIT**:

- If it's not used correctly, the `AsyncTask` can give you issues when rotating for instance, you can create memory leaks. You can find a lot of articles talking about DOs and DONTs of the `AsyncTask`.
- It's fine if you want to use `HttpURLConnection` and then parse the response manually, there's no problem with that, but you have to do by yourself that specific stuff while there are a lot of people that prefer using abstract libraries like Retrofit which under the hood does the same thing but probably too much better than you, and that let you take care of what is really important to you: your business logic. It's just my recommendation.

Comment: Thank for your answer. It appears that the problem is from the server and not from android.please check my update. As for stop using AsyncTask , can you explain more why?!

Comment: You should first check if sb.toString() contains htlm or json. And not blindly convert it to a json object. And there is nothing wrong with using HttpUrlConnection and Asynctask.

Comment: Note about asynctask having issues with orientation change is quite faulty and indicates you do not understand the reason said memory leaks can occur. Asynctask is also not bond to activity lifecycle

Comment: My fault! I wasn't clear enough. The `AsyncTask` by itself it's ok, but what I'm trying to explain is that the way people generally use it can generate problems if you don't decouple your code correctly and you declare the task inside the activity for example. Then, if you rotate your device you're generating a memory leak because the task will have a reference to the destroyed activity. My suggestion was only to use tools that handles those things for us, we don't need to go so deeper when there are reliable tools out there. Thanks for your note Marcin.